# LeanFT: Unable to invoke methods with non-primitive parameter: No object is registered with cookie: [object Object]

Tags: java, testing, hp-uft, leanft

I'm trying to invoke a method on a NativeObject, e.g.:

```
nativeObject.invokeMethod("scrollRectToVisible", new DynamicObjectProxy(new Rectangle()));
```

I came up with the idea to pass a DynamicObjectProxy as a method parameter as the "invokeMethod"-method of a NativeObject always returns a DynamicObjectProxy for non-primitive return types.
However, the following exception arrises:
`com.hp.lft.sdk.GeneralLeanFtException: no object is registered with cookie:[object Object]`

Invoking methods with primitive parameters works fine. If I pass the real object as a parameter, e.g.:

```
nativeObject.invokeMethod("scrollToRectVisible", new Rectangle());
```

The following exception arrises:

```
com.hp.lft.sdk.GeneralLeanFtException: Typeconflict (HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
```

I would highly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Why do you expect any of the provided examples to work? How would you scroll to an empty Rect object? And where is the `scrollToRectVisible` method coming from? How is it implemented? How does it work?

Comment: This is just an example. Taking any method from any swing Component, which needs a non primitive parameter, is going to lead to the 2nd exception above (GeneralLeanFtException: Typeconflict). I came up with the idea to wrap it into a DynamicObjectProxy as "invokeMethod" from NativeObject always returns a DynamicObjectProxy.  From the LeanFt-Java-Docs: invokeMethod(java.lang.String methodName, java.lang.Class<T> returnType, java.lang.Object... args). This is a bug in my opinion as returnType is always DynamicProxyObject, no matter what return type you specify.